# Xcode 7.3 crashing when debugging with breakpoints

Tags: xcode, xcode7, xcode8

I just install the Xcode 7.3 version. I can't debug at all because it's crashing when I try to use a breakpoint while I'm debugging. I tried removing Derive Data, Reboot my macbook, reinstall pods... but unfortunately nothing is working. Is someone having the same issue?

> Process:               Xcode [2631]
>   Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
>   Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
>   Version:               7.3 (10183.3)
>   Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-10183003000000000~2
>   App Item ID:           497799835
>   App External ID:       816750016
>   Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
>   Parent Process:        ??? [1]
>   Responsible:           Xcode [2631]
>   User ID:               502
>
> Date/Time:             2016-03-22 17:35:16.678 +0000
>   OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.4 (15E65)
>   Report Version:        11
>   Anonymous UUID:        352BCE12-8AEF-A28A-B5F1-214B55269668
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 2500 seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        30    Dispatch queue: DVTInvalidationPreventionQueue
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
>   Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
>   Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> VM Regions Near 0:
>   --> 
>       __TEXT                 00000001021a4000-00000001021a8000 [   16K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
>
> Application Specific Information:
>   ProductBuildVersion: 7D175
>
> Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
>   14.418349    DTXConnectionServices      0x000000010454fc3a initiating channel x1.c2 capability 642d65677561672d 766f72702d617461 654e2e7372656469 6174536b726f7774 0073636974736974
>   14.419261    DTXConnectionServices      0x000000010454fc3a initiating channel x1.c1 capability 756265642e65646f 2d65677561672d67 6f72702d61746164 702e737265646976 006f666e69636f72
>   71.740178    CFNetwork                  0x00007fff8d398447 TCP Conn 0x7fe21e691b50 SSL Handshake DONE
>   72.390183    CFNetwork                  0x00007fff8d398323 TCP Conn 0x7fe21e691b50 starting SSL negotiation
>   72.390333    CFNetwork                  0x00007fff8d396ced TCP Conn 0x7fe21e691b50 complete. fd: 50, err: 0
>   72.390574    CFNetwork                  0x00007fff8d4255c7 TCP Conn 0x7fe21e691b50 event 1. err: 0
>   72.582281    CFNetwork                  0x00007fff8d395fbf TCP Conn 0x7fe21e691b50 started
>   72.628957    CFNetwork                  0x00007fff8d359c42 Creating default cookie storage with process/bundle identifier
>   72.628957    CFNetwork                  0x00007fff8d359bda Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
>   72.628976    CFNetwork                  0x00007fff8d359a69 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton
>   72.650686    CFNetwork                  0x00007fff8d457510 NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
>
> Crashed Thread:        30    Dispatch queue: DVTInvalidationPreventionQueue
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
>   Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
>   Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Thread 30 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
>     rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000700003900628  rcx: 0x0000700003900338  rdx: 0x00007fe225f6d940
>     rdi: 0x0000700003900338  rsi: 0x000000000000003e  rbp: 0x00007000039005f0  rsp: 0x00007000039003f0
>      r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x00007fe215375800  r10: 0xf6c0d10bcec3bd6e  r11: 0x00007fe214fa1000
>     r12: 0x0000700003900628  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000001  r15: 0x00007fe215375800
>     rip: 0x000000010e3ae917  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Answer (score 52, accepted):

What solved it for me is setting the "Enable Clang Module Debugging" in Build Setting to NO.

Comment: Thanks! that fixed my problem

Comment: Thanks from me too, saved me a lot of headaches.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Literally wasted time to find xcode 7.3 bug . I donot understand, how  an IDE can crash repeatedly ?? This indeed seems to be a concern over stability of xcode development environment.

Comment: When I set this to NO, XCode does not allow my project to use '@import' statements.  I have many cocoapod dependencies that use '@import.

Comment: **Enable Clang Module Debugging** is not found in **XCode 7.3.1**. Is there any other option available to avoid the xcode crash issue?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051

Comment: From Apple release notes: 
The Enable Clang Module Debugging build setting has been removed in this release, which may cause slower build times and larger debug information. This feature is intended to reduce the size of debug information. Temporarily removing this setting reduces Xcode crashes and problems with incomplete information in the variables view. (25535528)
Note: The Enable Clang Module Debugging setting had been enabled by default. If you had previously disabled it, it now appears as a user-defined build setting named CLANG_ENABLE_MODULE_DEBUGGING, which can be removed.

Comment: XCode 8.0 has the same problem and this setting fixes it too.

Answer (score 0):

I set the "Enable Clang Module Debugging" in Build Setting to NO is still crashing.I find this answer while searching, and someone seems fixed this problem. Hope it helps, [How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this crash by removing my test target in my pod spec and updating my pods.

It may be enough to simply run

```
pod update
```

to fix this.