# Xcode 7.3.1 crashing with swift code when debugging with breakpoints

Tags: swift, xcode7

I have updated the Xcode to 7.3.1 but still Xcode is crash when I am debugging the swift code.

I also follow this Solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/36172742/1915700
But that particular option is not available in Xcode 7.3.1.

Comment: I got the solution.... Uninstall the XCode first and install the XCode again.

Comment: if this is what solves your problem. please make it answer, so it become helpful and noticable.

Answer (score 0):

follow the [link](http://www.jianshu.com/p/2fb2f37a3632)

`delete breakpoints_v2.plist`

try this method, hope this helps